# Can I use the magnitude of the SHAP values as the threshold for outlier detection?

Tags: python, outliers, shap, isolation-forest

I have a dataset which has ~60 columns and ~75000 rows. I used the isolation forest model to detect some outliers and do the shap plot to see the top features of these isolation forest.

My question is: Is it possible to use shap values as threshold for removing values? Like if I set the level of shap values for some certain variables, if shap values > or < threshold, they will be determined as outliers and can be removed. Is this executable? If so, how do I do this in python?

Comment: The logic behind isolation forest and shap values are absolute different: IF counts how remote some values are from the rest; shap values explain which features are most instrumental in splitting towards lower impurity.

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for the answer! My current thought is: As I already know the outliers by using IF, and I got the shap values for these outliers, so I want too explore if I can use these outliers' shap values as 'characteristics' so to perform as thresholds for removing data.And possibly using some of the groups that they are known to come in? I don't know if this is applicable, if not, what other ways I can do? My goal is : not just detect the anomalous data but also figure out which inputs to remove. Thank you!

Comment: Again, SV will sort your features in some hopefully meaningful order, but being outlier depends on a particular value of those features. Do you see the difference for sorting columns and seeing what's inside a column?